# Static Newbie: Are non-static variables in a static class/method implied static?

Tags: c#

When a website simultaneously hits the same static method that has non-static variables, are these variables static even though not declared static?  I would assume so, but I had to ask.

Another option would be that different executions of the same code have different internal variables, so this code wouldn't produce unexpected string lengths for example:

```
public static class MyClass 
{
    public static int getResult(string ext)
    {
        int length = est.length;  // One place in RAM or multiple?
        Thread.Sleep(5000);       // Does this stop program execution for others?
        return length;
    }
}
```

Question summary:

1. Are static method variables that are not declared static implied static, i.e. simultaneous execution of static code will affect each other?
2. or do these variables have their own storage each?
3. and does Thread.Sleep(5000) in a static method stop all user's execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're showing *local* variables. So no, those aren't static variables. Each time you invoke the method (including if it invoked itself recursively), you get a new set of variables. Different threads will *not* be sharing those variables. Note that this has nothing to do with the class being a static class. You need to differentiate between:

- Local variables, which belong to the method that declares them
- Instance variables, associated with a particular instance of the declaring type
- Static variables, associated with the declaring type itself (and not with any specific instance)

`Thread.Sleep` only makes the *current* thread sleep - if your application has multiple threads, the others will still be able to execute.

Comment: TYVM.  I created an example using LinqPad to prove it.  I had three threads counting up, counting down, and not counting, just reporting the variable contents.  Worked as you described.